# Why are objects not horizontally aligned when using rotation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

This is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \def\magnet at (#1,#2,#3){\draw [rotate=#3] (#1,#2) ellipse (0.8 and 0.4)
        node at (#1-0.4,#2) {N}
        node at (#1+0.4,#2) {S};}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \magnet at (1,0,30);
        \magnet at (3,0,30);
        \magnet at (5,0,30);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Why are the ellipses not horizontally aligned even when their centers have same y-value?

[image]

Comment: They are aligned: add `\draw (0,0) -- (30:7cm);`.

Comment: @percusse, nice. But I guess that the OP wants output as 3 rotated ellipses side by side on the *same row*.

Comment: @Sigur Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Ah OK. My bad. Then one possibility is `\draw[rotate around={#3:(#1,#2)}]....` . In your code (#1,#2) also picks up the rotation with respect to origin. You can alternatively write `\coordinate(temp) at (#1,#2);` before this line and use `\draw[rotate=30] (temp) ellipse ....` and adjust node text with respect to `(temp)`

Comment: @percusse Your suggestion works. Can you add it as an answer? I used
`\draw[rotate around={#3:(#1,#2)}]....`

Comment: Use Heiko's answer instead. It is more convenient.

Answer (score 12):

A solution via `pic`, a feature of TikZ 3.0:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  magnet/.pic={
    \draw
      ellipse (0.8 and 0.4)
      node at (-0.4, 0) {N}
      node at (0.4, 0) {S}
    ;
  },
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \path
         (1, 0) pic[rotate=30]{magnet}
         (3, 0) pic[rotate=30]{magnet}
         (5, 0) pic[rotate=30]{magnet}
      ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

By using \tikz in the definition, and dropping the ; at the end, the result is three ellipses next to each other.  Still learning tikz myself.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\magnet at (#1,#2,#3){\tikz \draw [rotate=#3] (#1,#2) ellipse (0.8 and 0.4)
    node at (#1-0.4,#2) {N}
    node at (#1+0.4,#2) {S}}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \magnet at (1,0,30);
    \magnet at (3,0,30);
    \magnet at (5,0,30);              
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```